# Xcode says Build is successful, but app is not installed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 with the deployment target set to 4.1 and the iOS is 4.2.1 on an iPhone 3Gs.  Whenever I build and run the application with the iPhone 3Gs as the target, it says "finished running 'app name' on 'iPhone 3Gs'.

- I have a provision profile setup for this iPhone 3Gs
- I checked organizer, and the circle to the right of the iPhone name is green
- I ran the same app on my iPhone 4s with the deployment target set to 4.1 and it installed and runs on my iPhone 4s.

Any ideas as to what might be going on that is not installing the app on the iPhone 3Gs?  I even tried searching for the app using spotlight, and nothing came up.

Thanks!

EDIT:

this is what appears in my device console log:

```
Fri May 18 15:27:39 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: Could not   receive USB message #6 from iTunes. Killing connection 
Fri May 18 15:27:39 unknown   com.apple.mobile.lockdown[16] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message 
Fri May 18 15:27:51   unknown MobileStorageMounter[4978] <Notice>: (0x3e7518b8) platform_supports_camera_import:   Platform is NOT configured for camera import 
Fri May 18 15:28:01 unknown     MobileStorageMounter[4978] <Notice>: (0x3e7518b8) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle
```

Comment: Check device console logs in XCode for that iPhone

Comment: Here's what the device console logs read:  Fri May 18 15:27:39 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iTunes. Killing connection
Fri May 18 15:27:39 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[16] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message

Fri May 18 15:27:51 unknown MobileStorageMounter[4978] <Notice>: (0x3e7518b8) platform_supports_camera_import: Platform is NOT configured for camera import
Fri May 18 15:28:01 unknown MobileStorageMounter[4978] <Notice>: (0x3e7518b8) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle timeout

Comment: Can you post that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have armv6 and armv7 for your 'Valid Architectures' in Build settings, because the 3Gs won't work on the defaulted armv7 only